# How to set size for an iframe based on its inner content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an iframe included in parent.html file.

I need to set the size of the iframe based on its inner content (child.html).

child.html will contain a lengthy text, with the following code at line

child.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight

I get a size equivalents to visible content part in the iframe and not its full size (not visible part).

Any idea what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

---------------------------- parent.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Parent</title>
    <script>
    window.name = 'parent';
    </script>
    <style>
    body {
    }
    #childIframe{

    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <iframe id="childIframe" src="child.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <script>

    var child = document.getElementById('childIframe');
    child.height = child.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";

    </script>
    </body>


    </html>
```

---------------------------- child.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Child</title>
</head>
<script>
window.name = 'child';
</script>

<body>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum pretium placerat enim, ut luctus orci porta quis. Suspendisse id dignissim nunc. Aenean non sapien in felis aliquet eleifend. Sed et nisi congue, pharetra ligula accumsan, accumsan diam. Praesent risus est, porttitor ut venenatis et, convallis non orci. Duis viverra finibus est, vel aliquam purus elementum finibus. Nunc ullamcorper rhoncus eros id pulvinar. Nam tellus nulla, pretium quis consequat sit amet, rutrum non augue.

.... very very long text here
</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please add a comment when down voting, was my question an illegitimate one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefered one:

```
function setHeight()
{
     var child = document.getElementById('childIframe');
     child.style.height = child.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

or

```
child.height = child.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
```

Iframe height attribute takes no units, while the style property does.

Do this on onload:

```
<iframe id="childIframe" src="child.html" scrolling="no" onload="setHeight()" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: using your code and the inspector i see body in child.html of size 1560px but at line child.style.height = child.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px"; I get always 150... what could be the problem?

Comment: We need to wait until completion

Answer (score 0):

We use code like this  ....

Script in head of Parent page :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function SetHeight(wParent,wChild) { // parent window, child window
    var f = wParent.frames["iFrameName"]; // whatever the iframe's name is
    if (f) f.style.height=(wChild.document.body.scrollHeight + 30)+"px";
}
</script>
```

if calling from Child page, add to onload event ..

```
<body onload='SetHeight(parent,window)'>
```

if calling from the parent page ..

```
SetHeight(window , window.frames["iFrameName"])
```

Which event ? if you need the code to be in the parent frame, then you need to do something to repeatedly check the state of the loading frame to check its state, perhaps using setTimeout. You will only be able to get the height of the document once the child page has loaded & rendered.

BUT

If the child page is from a different domain, then trying to do this will almost certainly give you an "Access Denied" error because javascript from a parent frame can't access attributes of a child from from a different domain.

Comment: Were comes the `this` keyword from. I think you meant this code to be in the iframes source html. Your code works but were to place it is not immediatly clear from your answer. But what if the owner has no control over the html page loaded inside the iframe. It needs to be done on the parent side not on the childs side.

Comment: @Mouser have amended the answer